# how to pass parameter to $(document).ready() within .xsl file

Tags: jquery, css, xslt, styles

have a windows app, which spits a web page, when button is clicked. the format of the web page is built in a .xsl file, while the content gets populated within a .cs file. The .xsl has some .css within the  tag, jquery within the  tag followed by some html and .xsl code.
the TABLE rows, whose colors are being set in the  tag, need to change, when the page loads,  depending on some value on the server side.

is there a way to pass that value from server side to jquery within the .xsl side.

here's a little part of the .xsl file

```js
          $( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#tEntSetup tr.datarow").hide();
          $("#tEntOrg tr.datarow").hide();
          $("#tCoSetup tr.datarow").hide();
          $("#tEmpCount tr.datarow").hide();
          $("#tRuleCode tr.datarow").hide();
          $('#tVersionDetails').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });
          $('#tEntSetup').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });
          $('#tEntOrg').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });
          $('#tCoSetup').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });
          $('#tEmpCount').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });
          $('#tRuleCode').on('click', 'tr.header',function(){
          $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(200);
          });

          $('#tVersionDetails tr.header').css('background-color','#0073C2');
          });
```

```css
         
          table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
          }
          td, th {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
          }
          tr.datarow th {
          background-color: #ffeedd;
          }
          .header {
          background-color: #3EAA48;
          color:#FFFFFF;
          cursor: pointer;
          }
          .datarow{
          background-color: whitesmoke;
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gridtable" id="tVersionDetails">
          <tr class="header"><th colspan="2" class="Title">Version Details</th></tr>
          <tr class="datarow">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Version</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//Information/ProductInformation/VersionInfo/data">
            <tr class="datarow">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="version"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
```

thanks so much for viewing my issue, and helping me out.

Comment: I don't see the  call to the server? You can include an <xsl;parameter name="apram">x</xsl:parameter> in your XSL, whose value gets set by the server before the transform, then used within the XSL as: <xsl:value-of select="$aparam" />

Comment: Bryn -how does the parameter get the value from server side ?

Comment: It depends on how you are doing the transform. You haven't shown the server side code, but there will be a way to add the xsl, the xml and to add values to parameters that you define.

Comment: Bryn - following is the server side code, which generates the xml and plugs in the xsl.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetProdInformation(bool useCustom,string connString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connString;
            UseCustom = useCustom;
            XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();`enter code here`
            XmlElement root = XD.CreateElement("Information");
            XmlElement si = XD.CreateElement("ProductInformation");
            root.AppendChild(si);

            DataSet dsProdInfo = null;
            try
            {
                using (DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(GetConnString()))
                {
                    helper.ClearParameters();
                    helper.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    helper.CommandText = "dbo.pro_product_info_get";
                    dsProdInfo = helper.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (dsProdInfo != null && dsProdInfo.Tables.Count > 0)
                        SetTableNames(ref dsProdInfo);

                    CheckForPayrollInstallation(dsProdInfo);
                }

                si.AppendChild(VersionInfo(XD, dsProdInfo));
                si.AppendChild(PayrollInstalled(XD));
                si.AppendChild(EnterpriseSetup(XD, dsProdInfo));
                si.AppendChild(EnterpriseOrganizations(XD, dsProdInfo));
                si.AppendChild(CompanySetup(XD, dsProdInfo));
                si.AppendChild(EmployeeCount(XD, dsProdInfo));

                si.AppendChild(DetailedCheckBox(XD));
                if (IsDetailedCheckBoxChecked)
                    si.AppendChild(RuleCodeTables(XD, dsProdInfo));

                root.AppendChild(si);
                XD.AppendChild(root);

                String sLogFileName = string.Format(XMLFileName, Path.GetTempPath());
                XD.Save(sLogFileName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                dsProdInfo.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your original question instead of adding an answer, so all the info is in the same place.

Your server side code does not show the xsl transform. It will be something like this:

```
            string serverside_p = "a value";
            XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
            argsList.AddParam("serverside_param", "", serverside_p);

            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
            transform.Load("your_xsl.xsl");

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("result.xml"))
            {
                transform.Transform("your_xml.xml", argsList, sw);
            }
```

Your XSL needs to have a parameter that matches the parameter name you are passing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="serverside_param" />

....

<!-- To output the value -->

<xsl:value-of select="$serverside_param" />

<!-- or put it inside an attribute value -->
<td class="{$serverside_param}_class">cell value </td>
```

However, as you are building your XML on the server, why can't you add the parameter value directly into the XML and access it like any other XML attribute?